# Is there a way we can render more than one view in same template in Django?

Tags: django, templates, view

I'm starting a data analysis project in django and want to show text data and graph data in single tamplate which are generated from different views. Is it a good practice to do this way or I should rander two different template for text data and graph data?

Comment: nope, you have to use one view to render one page. But you can use iframe to load contexts from another view

Comment: What do you mean by generated from different views? You can get both data in the view and render them in one template

Comment: @grouchoboy.. i want to create two views one for text data and another for graph data and one html file to desplay both text data and graphs. I don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. A view is responsible for creating a response based on the request and returning it, and can use whatever approach makes sense to do so. A template is one tool to do so, and nothing stops you from using a given template in multiple views. If you're using functional views, it might look something like this:

```
def display_text(request):
    context = ...
    return render(request, "data.html", context)

def display_graph(request):
    context = ... # some different context than the text case
    return render(request, "data.html", context)
```

The details may vary - the point is just that there's nothing tying the template to just one view.

Whether this is a good idea or not depends on how much of the template behavior is shared between your two cases. In general, I would instead recommend factoring out the shared parts of the template to a parent template and using [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) to specialize the different behavior that's specific to the different data types without repeating the shared parts. Even if the current display behavior is the same, using two different templates makes it easier to change that in the future should you want to.

If a single template can genuinely handle both cases without needing to determine what the data type is, and you don't anticipate changing that, it could be a reasonable choice to reuse a single template in both views rather than create type-specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one base template, and then in a block of that template display the data

`base_data.html`

```
  some html
{% block data %}
{% endblock %}
   more html
```

`text_data.html`

```
{% extends 'base_data.html' %}

{% block data %}
   html to display the text data
{% endblock %}
```

`graph_data.html`

```
{% extends 'base_data.html' %}

{% block data %}
 html to display the graph data
{% endblock %}
```

`views.py`

```
def display_text_data(request):
    # your code
    return render(request, 'text_data.html', context)

def display_grapth_data(request):
    # your code
    return render(request, 'graph_data.html', context)
```

I don't know exactly if you want the above or if you want in one html display the two, text and graph, is is the second it will be:

`data.html`

```
display text_data using textdata context

display graph data using graphdata context
```

`views.py`

```
def show_data(request):
    textdata = # get text data context
    graphdata = # get graph data context
    return render(request, 'data.html', context={'textdata': textdata, 'graphdata': graphdata}
```

Comment: I can create one view and one template. But i'm concerned because then it has so much code in one view. That's why i'm asking two or more views and one html file to display context from views at same time. I don't get my answer but thanks for taking your time.